# Are there any bad design patterns?

Tags: design-patterns

There are a lot of design patterns and its pretty obvious that the patterns themselves are not silver bullets. However, in your experience, have there been any patterns that have consistently resulted in problems further on? I guess I'm asking if there are certain patterns that after some time turn from a solution into a problem in their own right?

I am currently dealing with a Singleton class that falls into this category and I would like to ask everyone if there are other such patterns that they have encountered.

Comment: Lots of people would put Singleton in that category.

Comment: I was thinking of Singleton myself when I posted the question. I'm dealing with a singleton class that is now a problem because its a singleton. That's the reason for the question - to tap into the collective knowledge base and see of there were other such patterns that came to mind.

Comment: I can see the question is already answered. But here is a link to some anti-patterns for Java but can probably apply to other languages too. http://mindprod.com/jgloss/unmain.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, these are called [antipatterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti_pattern). The only one I have ever dealt with (that I know of off the top of my head) is the [waterfall model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_model). Rather than trying to describe them, I would highly suggest reading the first link. It has a lot of insightful information!

To add a little humor, you mentioned "not silver bullets"... [No Silver Bullet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet) :)

Comment: wrt "No Silver Bullet" -- I'd argue that a number of designs as "accidental complexity" often introduced by limitations in a language but... +1 for mentioning *antipatterns*, which entirely much answers [and closes] the question.

Comment: Thanks! +1 for the humor that is actually relevant :)

Answer (score 2):

As Austin stated in his answer, if your wanting to know what to avoid it is best to read up on anti-patterns -- but I would add 'code smells' as well.

Design patterns are only beneficial when applied to solve the problem they are made to solve.  I am often relearning that technology does not solve problems -- people do, and then technology is used to implement the solution.  Each design patterns is a solution to a specific problem, and when implemented solves that problem.  When the wrong solution is implemented, the problem does not get solved; and usually gets much worse.

You, like many others before you, have incountered a Singleton used to solve a problem it wasn't meant to solve.  Best to step back, look at it again and identify the problem (or problems) that need addressed and implement the design pattern or patterns that solve them.

In short, it is good to recognize the anti-patterns or 'code smells', but in order to avoid trouble with design patterns it is best to understand exactly what problem they were meant to solve, and only implement them to sovle that particular problem.